# Why my mac can not access external traffic to other port except 80, 443, 22?

Tags: network, tcp

I can access all website with standard port(80 and 443) example: domain.com, but why I cant access example.com:3030? I cant connect to MySQL and PostgreSQL, via direct host/port to external IP, but I can connect to MySQL from localhost.

I can connect to all external/public hostname/ip, if I try this command:

```
curl domain.com:6030
```

the result is

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to domain.com port 6030: Operation timed
>   out

but I can connect to port 80,443 and 21.     I can open domain.com:6030 using another device, but why I can not using my mac?

How to fix that? I never turn on firewall.

Comment: How do you know that those ports are open on the remote end? “Operation timeout” means it waited fir a response and got nothing.  If it was a firewall, it would be “connection refused”

Comment: @Allan I can access those ports using other devices except my current mac

Comment: From the same network?  Are those devices on the same network as the Mac?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Is your Mac configured to use a proxy? (Check System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies to find out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry all, the problem is caused by VPN application, after I turn off that I can access all port again. I didnt know if that running because that app not in the dock list, only in menu bar.

Thank @jaume for giving me the clue about that app.